# plt.show() causes the jupyter console to freeze if it is run from a script

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-console

I am not sure this is a bug or some of my misunderstanding.
If the first case applies, please let me know so I will use the appropriate issue tracker.

Consider the following `./myscript.py` :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

tf = 20
f0 = 1
fs = 4*np.pi*f0
t = np.arange(0, tf, 1/fs)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t))
plt.show()
```

If I run the above script through a `jupyter console` through the following command:

```
In [1]: run -i ./myscript.py
```

then the console freezes and I have to `<c-c>` and then restart the kernel to be able to continue to work.
If I modify the above script by removing the last line and I run the following:

```
In [1]: run -i ./myscript.py
In [2]: plt.show()
```

then things work perfectly, but it is very annoying to manually call `plt.show()` as shown in the latter example.

How to solve the problem?

EDIT: More details. After I stopped the kernel with `<c-c>` and I try to run any command from jupyter console, I get the following error message:

```
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/manim_ce/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py:787: UserWarning: The kernel did
 not respond to an is_complete_request. Setting `use_kernel_is_complete` to False.
  warn('The kernel did not respond to an is_complete_request. '
```

Comment: It works for me, on Windows with `matplotlib 3.5.1`. Are you on linux?

Comment: MacOSX Ventura. I can’t tell right now the matplotlib version because I am out watching the AS Roma’s football match but I’ll provide such an info later on today/tomorrow.

Comment: `matplotlib-base 3.7.1 py311h99a5f44_0 conda-forge`,  `matplotlib-inline 0.1.6 pyhd8ed1ab_0 conda-forge`

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**: I had to add a `plt.pause()` before plotting. The above script has been modified as:

```
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.pause(0.1) # <==== ADDED THIS!
ax.plot(t, np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t))
plt.show()
...
```